# Defaulting date time zone to UTC for Jodatime's DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I am currently creating UTC DateTime objects using the current idiom

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Is there any way to default so I can create UTC-based DateTime objects using the default constructor so it is more implicit?

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you only want to set the default timezone for joda time, use [`DateTimeZone.setDefault`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#setDefault%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29).

---

If you want to change the timezone that the *whole jvm* uses use [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29) method. Just be sure to set it early as it can be cached by joda time.. quoted from [DateTimeZone.getDefault](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29):

> The default time zone is derived from the system property user.timezone. If that is null or is not a valid identifier, then the value of the JDK TimeZone default is converted. If that fails, UTC is used.

Comment: note, that will affect the _whole_ jvm, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Added how to set it "only" for joda time (`DateTimeZone.setDefault`).

Comment: I want to stress the caution by jtahlborn. `TimeZone.setDefault` affects *every thread* of *every app* running in the same JVM. Calling this method can create all kinds of confusion and unexpected behavior in other classes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `DateTimeZone.setDefault`. Simplifies things to get the server behave as if it's in UTC. MongoDB would do well to make these a bit simpler.

Answer (score 15):

If you are really concerned about the extra chars, then just create a helper method:

```
public static DateTime newUTCDateTime() {
  return new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}
```