# MongoDB, Java: Retrieve date property as UTC

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm saving some entities to a Mongo database, these have Joda DateTime properties which have UTC set as a timezone. While saving works fine and I see the properties with correct values in the collection, once I retrieve the entities through Java the timezone gets set to UTC+2 again.

This is in the collection:

```
"created" : ISODate("2013-07-26T20:36:57.890Z")
```

I'm using Spring-Data-MongoDB to access the database.

```
Category category = mongoTemplate.findById(id, Category.class);
```

And I end up with this:

```
2013-07-26T23:05:56.439+02:00
```

Is there a way to tell Mongo do return the timezone stored in the date?

Hints appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Actually mongo returns what it is in the database, but your program prints it using local settings. I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver is returning what the database has as a java.util.Date object.  It knows nothing of the timezone that time represents.  It does not store the Timezone anywhere.  Mongo Shell always presents a time value as UTC.

That being said, if you want to work with it in your application code as UTC always, I think there is a way to tell the JODA library to do this:  [Defaulting date time zone to UTC for Jodatime's DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397715/defaulting-date-time-zone-to-utc-for-jodatimes-datetime)